# haproxy 503 no server available to handle this request

Tags: haproxy

I'm new to HAproxy and have been following guides to get me started. I think I got the set up I need but when I try to load my web site domain I get a

```
503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.
```

this is my HAproxy set up:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    debug
    stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log global
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    acl app0 hdr(host) -i mywebsite.com

    use_backend srvs_app0 if app0


backend srvs_app0
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server host0 10.10.104.41:1038 check


listen stats *:1936
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version
    stats auth someuser:password
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking for, or where I can start to look for a possible problem.

I'm looking for help in either pointing me on the right direction or maybe even point out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured HAProxy to connect to `10.10.104.41` port `1038`. The error message tells that it is unable to connect to this port.

The reason could be one of these:

1. The app server at that IP / Port is not started.
2. The firewall on that server is not allowing external connections.
3. There is no route to the IP of the app server.
4. The app server IP / Port is incorrect.

In order to give more precise instructions, details are needed on the structure of your setup and configuration of the app server.

Comment: *"The error message tells that it is unable to connect to this port."*  Not necessarily. That's one of several possible causes of 503. There is also no default backend, and 503 is equally applicable to a request that did not get a backend assigned, because (in this case, perhaps) the ACL didn't match.